# What's the general order of index for SQL Server clauses?

Tags: indexing, sql-server-2000

```
SELECT Col1
FROM   Tab1
INNER JOIN Tab2 ON Tab1.Col2 = Tab2.Col2
WHERE  Tab1.Col3 = "some ID"
GROUP  BY Col1, Col4
ORDER  BY Col4 DESC
```

What would be the general way to create a covering index for the above case?

Is it like the columns from

1. ORDER BY
2. GROUP BY
3. WHERE
4. JOIN
5. SELECT

which is like

```
INDEX (Col4, Col1, Col3, Col2) ?
```

What I use is SQL Server 2000

Comment: For the `SELECT`, you should have an index on `(Col3)` to handle the `WHERE` clause - but for the `ORDER BY`, your index should be on `(Col4)`, and for the `GROUP BY` it should be on `(Col1, Col4)` - in short: you won't be able to handle this with a single index

Comment: Isn't covering index better if the query is used frequently?

Comment: Yes of course - but you won't be able to create a covering index that satisfies all the requirements at the same time.....

Comment: In this case, I only have few columns. I just want to know what's the better order of Index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I found by testing

•   First should be the JOIN

o   Index field order should be the reverse of JOIN order [bottom up]

o   If JOIN ON PK, then any Index you create on the table starting the PK field will NOT be used. Server will only use the PK.

•   Then WHERE

o   Index field order should be the reverse of WHERE order [bottom up]

•   Then GROUP BY

•   Then ORDER BY

•   Then SELECT [if doing Covering Index]

Also Index any computed columns

Having partial indexes for a View/Sproc doesn’t speed up. If few columns indexed on a GROUP BY in a multi table query, the index slows it down. Originally it uses PK and it is fast. So don’t bother partial indexes on multi table queries

If there is a SQL statement executed on a View, there is no performance improvement if you index the SQL Statement. The index should be based on the View

`Select * from Leasedetailsqry where status ='Active' And (territory LIKE 'Quebec')  ORDER BY id`

Indexing Territory, Status is not giving any performance improvement. You should index based on the View `Leasedetailsqry`